# Calculate Age from Date of Birth

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the following code to calculate age from date of birth
The code works in ASP.NET Web Forms Page..
But it is not working on MasterPage.......
ScriptManager tag is included in Master Page

```
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dob" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Date of Birth : </asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                         <asp:TextBox ID="dob" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" > 
                             </asp:TextBox>
                       <cc1:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="dob" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="SelectDate" ID="CalendarExtender1"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                          function SelectDate(e) {

                           var PresentDay = new Date();

                            var dateOfBirth = e.get_selectedDate();

                             var months = (PresentDay.getMonth() - dateOfBirth.getMonth() + (12 * (PresentDay.getFullYear() - dateOfBirth.getFullYear())));

                         alert("Your age : " + Math.floor(months / 12) + " Years");

                         document.getElementById("txtage").value = Math.floor(months / 12);

                             }

</script>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="dob" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Date of Birth is required." />
                    </div>
                </div>


                 <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server"  CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Text="Age : "> </asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtage"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                      </div>
                </div>
```

Update ::

I solved it by using the following code

Date of Birth :

```
                          function SelectDate(e) {

                           var PresentDay = new Date();

                            var dateOfBirth = e.get_selectedDate();

                             var months = (PresentDay.getMonth() - dateOfBirth.getMonth() + (12 * (PresentDay.getFullYear() - dateOfBirth.getFullYear())));

                         //alert("Your age : " + Math.floor(months / 12) + " Years");
                         document.getElementById('<%=age.ClientID %>').value = Math.floor(months / 12);
```

}

```
</script>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="dob" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Date of Birth is required." />
                    </div>
                      <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="age" runat="server"  CssClass="col-md-3 control-label" Text="Age : "> </asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         <asp:TextBox ID="age"  runat="server" CssClass="col-md-12 form-control" />
                      </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: The AJAX Control Toolkit uses `FindControl()` method to locate the extender. However, this method works differently on Master pages, so the method can not find the extender.

Comment: I solved it by using the following code